# Calculate difference between two dates and count the number of occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the difference between two dates and in the same query trying to count the frequency of occurence.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,[Date1],[Date2]) AS 'Mydate'
     , count ([Mydate])    
  FROM Table1
 group 
    by 'Mydate'
```

I am expecting the query to calculate and count but getting an error msg "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."
what I am expecting is, something like this:

```
Mydate  Count
0        5
1        4
2        5
```

Can someone help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this doesn't look like `MySQL` rather `SQL Server`. Secondly you can't use the alias in `Count()` function like that. Rather say `count(*)`

```
  SELECT DATEDIFF(day,[Date1],[Date2]) AS 'Mydate', 
         Count (*)    
    FROM Table1
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,[Date1],[Date2])
```

Comment: It is sql-server. Yes, I realise that but don't know the best way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, changing the group by clause solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot group by an alias:

```
SELECT 'Mydate', Cnt
FROM   (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, [Date1], [Date2]) AS 'Mydate', 
               Count(*) Cnt
        FROM   Table1) T1
GROUP BY 'Mydate'
```